# Best method for predicting a binary DV from multiple IVs with time series data in R or Python?

Tags: r, time-series, python, glmm, lstm

Let's say I have a dataset of 100.000 cases that contains 5 variables recorded over a period of time in long format, like this:

```
ID DATE       V1 V2 ... DV
1  01/01/2017 4  3      0
1  01/02/2017 3  4      1
1  01/03/2017 1  5      1
2  01/01/2017 5  1      0
2  01/02/2017 4  2      0
2  01/03/2017 4  3      1
```

I now want to predict the likelihood for a given case ID where DV is currently 0 to switch to DV = 1, based on all cases that have already switched from 0 to 1. It would also be acceptable to simply classify these "unswitched" cases as 0 or 1.

Which method is the most suited for this type of problem?

Things to consider:

1. Every case starts out at DV = 0.
2. The value usually doesn't go back to 0 once it changes to 1. It can happen, but if it makes the analysis easier, that can be ignored.
3. The dataset is pretty big - I could go back several years for most cases
4. Not every case starts at the same time. Some have years of historical data, some just a day. Given the sample size, however, one could ignore the newer cases if it makes things easier.

I am open to ML-solutions (maybe LSTM-RNN?) or more classical techniques (GLMM? But which specific GLMM and how?). I'm just really having trouble finding some examples / responses that I can understand and that can be transferred to my specific use case. I am familiar with multivariate methods such as linear regression, logistic regression or structural equation modeling, but I have never worked with time series before, so aside from a pointer towards one or two concrete models that would be appropriate here, I could really use some tutorials or books with applied examples, since everything I can find is completely overwhelming to me.